# Backspace not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have built a calculator where a user can either click on the buttons or s/he can select the variables from the drop down. Insertion using keyboard is denied. Now when I click on the highlighted back arrow button which has been put for backspace functionality, only the character present at the right most position is deleted even if my cursor is placed in between the expression using mouse. Is there a workaround to remove the character right before the position where I place my cursor? I am using the below condition on left arrow click:

```
formulaText.value = formulaText.value.slice(0, formulaText.value.lastIndexOf("("));
```

[image]

Comment: Look at `Selection` and `Range` to get the position of the caret.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `selectionStart` property on the `input` element. More information is on [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement). A working example is below.

```js
function getCursorPosition(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id).selectionStart;
}

function checkCursorPosition() {
  alert(getCursorPosition('testInput'));
}

function backspace() {
  var element = document.getElementById('testInput');
  var cursorPosition = getCursorPosition('testInput');
  
  element.value = element.value.substring(0, cursorPosition - 1) + element.value.substring(cursorPosition);
  element.selectionStart = element.selectionEnd = cursorPosition - 1;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="testInput" value="Example text" />
<button onclick="checkCursorPosition()">Check Cursor Position</button>
<button onclick="backspace()">Backspace</button>
```

Comment: I think you should use selectionStart and selectionEnd so you can backspace an entire selection

Comment: @CharlieWynn That's true, the entire selection could be removed. I chose to just remove a single character in this case though, as the OP asked for a way to remove the _character_ immediately preceding the cursor.

Comment: Definitely nothing wrong with your solution, everything he asked for